# QGIS Web Client cannot select Map Layer or use Layer Order

Tags: qgis, qgis-web-client, web

I have installed the QGIS Web Client from git with the install.sh script and went directly to copy a QGIS project in the project directory (with map layers in Postgis). After struggling with CRS (in the end I needed to set the project to 3857 when my layers are in 4326) and configuring properly the OWS properties I could obtain a nice result. However, I am not able to select/deselect map layers neither to use "Layer Order".

Testing many settings, I realized that I cannot even have the examples "Hello World" and "Natural Earth" working at all even after a re-install. The former just shows OSM and the latter is stuck on "Loading Map".

I can't figure out what is wrong, even looking at the information given in the log.

Platform is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. QWC from git has bugs... The above problems can be solve as following:

1) To be able to select and deselect layers and use "Layer Order", in Webgisinit.js in site/js line 1197 change updateLayerOrderPanel by updateLayerOrderPanelVisibilities.

2) To access the examples permissions on the data directory need to be changed. One need to check details of the why but changing to 777 solves the problem.